# Can I use Firebase when disabled COPPA in Play Console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Can I use Firebase features like analytics when my app is classified as age 0 and above ?( I disabled the option "target children under 13 years")

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting terms-of-service.

Comment: Why? This is a seroius question I am asking myself,because I do not want to violate any terms of COPPA.I do not know were to ask elsewere

Comment: Stack Overflow targets developers, not lawyers. I'm not saying your question is bad, just that it's off-topic for Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140561/are-terms-of-service-questions-okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you do not collect personal information from children below 13.